# Unity, Save cubemap to one circle image

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have cubemap. I need to save it in a circular image, for example in PNG. Many hours of searching on the Internet in what I have failed. How I do it? Is that possible?

I have image: joxi.ru/zANd66wSl6Kdkm

I need to save in png: joxi.ru/12MW55wT40LYjr Part code, which help you:

```
tex.SetPixels(cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.PositiveZ)); 
bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG(); 
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/" + cubemap.name +"_PositiveZ.png", bytes);
```

Comment: Way to vague of a question for anyone to be able to help you. You need to save a cubemap to a circular image? What software are you using... What is the code you have tried to write? What errors are you getting with this code? Need specifics to help.

Comment: I have cubemap: http://joxi.ru/zANd66wSl6Kdkm
I need to save in png: http://joxi.ru/12MW55wT40LYjr
Part code, which help you:
tex.SetPixels(cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.PositiveZ));
      bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();     
      File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/"  + cubemap.name +"_PositiveZ.png", bytes);

Comment: Okay, DavidR, thaks. I'm beginner in http://stackoverflow.com/ . But can you help me? How to save cubemap in texture?
I use UNITY3D, coding in c#

Comment: Sorry don't know much about Unity but the way the question is now, you should hopefully get someone to help you soon. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, good luck you too. May the Force be with you)

Comment: For what reason do you want to save the *spheremap*? Will you use it from shaders, or just want to show it in the assets during development?

Comment: Just want to get the png, and yes, i use it in future.

Comment: I like the question, but Malware Bytes blocks the first URL as Trojan.  I'm just the messenger.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class that inherits ScriptableWizard class that will render a cubemap from a specific transform. Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;

public class RenderCubemapWizard : ScriptableWizard
{

public Transform renderFromPosition;
public Cubemap cubemap;

void OnWizardUpdate()
{
    string helpString = "Select transform to render from and cubemap to render into";
    bool isValid = (renderFromPosition != null) && (cubemap != null);
}

void OnWizardCreate()
{
    // create temporary camera for rendering
    GameObject go = new GameObject("CubemapCamera");
    go.AddComponent<Camera>();
    // place it on the object
    go.transform.position = renderFromPosition.position;
    go.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
    // render into cubemap      
    go.GetComponent<Camera>().RenderToCubemap(cubemap);

    // destroy temporary camera
    DestroyImmediate(go);

    ConvertToPng();
}

[MenuItem("GameObject/Render into Cubemap")]
static void RenderCubemap()
{
    ScriptableWizard.DisplayWizard<RenderCubemapWizard>(
        "Render cubemap", "Render!");
}

void ConvertToPng()
{
    Debug.Log(Application.dataPath + "/" +cubemap.name +"_PositiveX.png");
    var tex = new Texture2D (cubemap.width, cubemap.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    // Read screen contents into the texture        
    tex.SetPixels(cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.PositiveX));        
    // Encode texture into PNG
    var bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();      
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/"  + cubemap.name +"_PositiveX.png", bytes);       

    tex.SetPixels(cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.NegativeX));
    bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();     
      File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/"  + cubemap.name +"_NegativeX.png", bytes);       

      tex.SetPixels(cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.PositiveY));
      bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();     
    File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/"  + cubemap.name +"_PositiveY.png", bytes);       

      tex.SetPixels(cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.NegativeY));
      bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();     
      File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/"  + cubemap.name +"_NegativeY.png", bytes);       

      tex.SetPixels(cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.PositiveZ));
      bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();     
      File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/"  + cubemap.name +"_PositiveZ.png", bytes);       

      tex.SetPixels(cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.NegativeZ));
      bytes = tex.EncodeToPNG();     
      File.WriteAllBytes(Application.dataPath + "/"  + cubemap.name   +"_NegativeZ.png", bytes);       
    DestroyImmediate(tex);

    }
}
```

This basically creates a new cubemap from the given position that you specify from within the wizard (to use the wizard go to GameObject in the top menu and at the bottom of the list you'll see 'Render into Cubemap').  It will then grab the six positions of the cubemap and convert it into a PNG file from with in the ConvertToPng() function.  This works for me and it should work for you since it essentially only needs a transform position.
Sorry for how long it is tried to simplify it but this as simplified as I could make it.

Here are the links that helped me come to this conclusion:

[How to convert a face to png](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/9189/how-can-i-extract-the-individual-faces-from-a-gene.html)

[Unity's scriptable wizard for rendering a cubemap](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.RenderToCubemap.html)

Comment: P.S. This will save the .png files to the assets folder of your project. It might also take a little for Unity to display in the assets panel.

Comment: Thanks for help, but... I did something similar: 6 screenshots I can to receive too. I need to get of filled cubemap one "round" texture.
an exemplary example: joxi.ru/12MW55wT40LYjr .

Comment: That looks like they took a screenshot of the inspector of the cubemap and then cropped out the round preview portion of the cubemap.

Comment: I was just cut, for example. I do not need the faces, i want take texture from render cubemap and encode it to png or any other format.

Comment: I just cropped my [cubemap](http://imgur.com/UhQArgw) looks the same as the link.

Comment: Do you just need it more automated or is there something wrong with just cropping it?

Comment: I need to save with help to script, friend)

Comment: I have filled cubemap and i need take it as 2d texture.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct approach that allows for a single compressed cubemap texture. After .png texture is saved, just set its settings to cube & the compression settings you want.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.IO;

public class RenderCubemapUtil : ScriptableWizard
{
    public Transform renderFromPosition;
    public int size = 512;
    public string newCubmapPath;

    void OnWizardUpdate()
    {
        isValid = renderFromPosition != null && size >= 16 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(newCubmapPath);
    }

    void OnWizardCreate()
    {
        if (!isValid) return;

        // create temporary camera for rendering
        var go = new GameObject("CubemapCamera");
        go.AddComponent<Camera>();

        try
        {
            // place it on the object
            go.transform.position = renderFromPosition.position;
            go.transform.rotation = Quaternion.identity;

            // create new texture
            var cubemap = new Cubemap(size, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);

            // render into cubemap
            go.GetComponent<Camera>().RenderToCubemap(cubemap);

            // convert cubemap to single horizontal texture
            var texture = new Texture2D(size * 6, size, cubemap.format, false);
            int texturePixelCount = (size * 6) * size;
            var texturePixels = new Color[texturePixelCount];

            var cubeFacePixels = cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.PositiveX);
            CopyTextureIntoCubemapRegion(cubeFacePixels, texturePixels, size * 0);
            cubeFacePixels = cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.NegativeX);
            CopyTextureIntoCubemapRegion(cubeFacePixels, texturePixels, size * 1);

            cubeFacePixels = cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.PositiveY);
            CopyTextureIntoCubemapRegion(cubeFacePixels, texturePixels, size * 3);
            cubeFacePixels = cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.NegativeY);
            CopyTextureIntoCubemapRegion(cubeFacePixels, texturePixels, size * 2);

            cubeFacePixels = cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.PositiveZ);
            CopyTextureIntoCubemapRegion(cubeFacePixels, texturePixels, size * 4);
            cubeFacePixels = cubemap.GetPixels(CubemapFace.NegativeZ);
            CopyTextureIntoCubemapRegion(cubeFacePixels, texturePixels, size * 5);

            texture.SetPixels(texturePixels, 0);

            // write texture as png to disk
            var textureData = texture.EncodeToPNG();
            File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, $"{newCubmapPath}.png"), textureData);

            // save to disk
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssetIfDirty(cubemap);
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
            AssetDatabase.Refresh();
        }
        finally
        {
            // destroy temporary camera
            DestroyImmediate(go);
        }
    }

    private void CopyTextureIntoCubemapRegion(Color[] srcPixels, Color[] dstPixels, int xOffsetDst)
    {
        int cubemapWidth = size * 6;
        for (int y = 0; y != size; ++y)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x != size; ++x)
            {
                int iSrc = x + (y * size);
                int iDst = (x + xOffsetDst) + (y * cubemapWidth);
                dstPixels[iDst] = srcPixels[iSrc];
            }
        }
    }

    [MenuItem("GameObject/Render into Cubemap")]
    static void RenderCubemap()
    {
        DisplayWizard<RenderCubemapUtil>("Render cubemap", "Render!");
    }
}
#endif
```